# fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects crashes on iOS 10 beta 1 and Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, ios10

Summary:

When I try to access the `fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects` app crashes and printed error as:

> fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element
>   type

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Call `fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects` after fetchedResultsController.performFetch.
2. Try to convert the `fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects` to `NSManagedObjects`.
3. App Crashes.

Expected Results:

`fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects` should be accessible in Swift.

iOS Version: `iOS 10 beta 1`

Xcode Version : `8.0 beta`

Swift : `2.3`

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please share the code you have used?

Comment: This issue has been resolved in Swift 3.0 syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved once I upgraded my Swift code to `Swift 3.0`.

Thanks!